# jaudiotagger library - creating m4a tag reading file

Tags: java, audio, metadata

I'm new to Java enviroment, recently I've been trying to create a simple mp3 tag reading file. Everything went ok until I tried to read tags from m4a file. After reading all API documentation and examples sadly I have still no idea how to scrypt m4a tag reading method. Could you please give me an example of working m4a tag reading method, so I could learn from it, with some simple clarification. I'd be very pleased.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```java
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read("test.mp4");
Tag tag = f.getTag();
Iterator<TagField> i = tag.getFields()
while(i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

The problem you might be having is that mp3 can be read either using the generic interface which is the same for all formats (the above code is using that) or using the mp3 specific interface that deals with ID3 frames. So if you did mp3s using that interface then the code for the other formats is very different.

Comment: I'm  getting and exception in your very first line: org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.CannotReadException: <song.m4a> :Unable to find next atom because identifier is invalid ��������